# Why does this Simple HTML DOM Parser next_sibling fail?

Tags: php

With this page.html

```
<table>
  <tr>eeny</tr>
  <tr>meany</tr>
  <tr>miny</tr>
  <!--comment-->
  <tr>mo</tr>
</table>
```

this code

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php'; // V1.5, latest 2015-09-20
$html = file_get_html('page.html');
print ($r = $html->find('tr',0)); // eeny - OK
print ($r = $r->next_sibling()); // meany - OK
print ($r = $r->next_sibling()); // miny - OK
print ($r = $r->next_sibling()); // <blank> - FAIL
?>
```

fails to print the 'mo'.

Why?

Comment: Obviously because of comment?

Comment: if you check source, you will see that : <!--comment--> is actually printed out. It is next_sibling() in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but no, comment is not printed.

Comment: why don't you `foreach($r as $r)` and the inside that you could print all the results...?